# How to Test a Bash File in Terminal

Tags: bash

I've been trying to make a bash file for newbie Linux users and I wanted to know if there is a way to test the bash file before running it.
Can I just see the result of my bash file in the terminal and not actually run it?

For example, I don't want to actually update and upgrade my system when I run this script, I just want to see the result of my bash file, whether it gives me back some error or not.
Wanted to know if there is a way to just see the result, like see the result of my 'echo' commands and etc.

```
echo ---------------

echo hello and welcome to the automized bash file for your new linux distro!

echo ---------------

sudo apt-get update -y ; sudo apt-get upgrade -y ; sudo apt-get autoremove -y ; sudo apt-get autoclean -y ; sudo apt-get clean -y 


echo ---------------

echo as you were drinking your coffee, 
echo your linux distro got updated, and autocleaned as well!
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give an example with some code. It sounds like you're asking how to run a script without actually running it, which doesn't make any sense, so I'm sure that's not what you mean. Are you looking for a linter? like, something that checks for syntax errors and other problems? If so, try [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: I sometimes test scripts by putting `echo` before potentially dangerous commands, so they won't actually run, just print what *would've* happened. But this requires knowing which are the potentially dangerous commands and what the rest of the script will do without them (and also may require special treatment if output's redirected somewhere).

Comment: A bash "script" is simply a collection of commands you could enter on the command line. The script just allows you to run the wanted commands sequentially in it's own process (subshell). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will check the syntax for you, but other than just executing the individual commands one-by-one, there really isn't a "dry-run" test. You can enable debug output by running your script with `bash -x yourscriptname` and bash will output each command and the result. To run your script, `./yourscriptname`, don't forget to make it executable, `chmod +x yourscriptname`

Comment: @wjandrea 
ShellCheck ShellCheck worked pretty good! Thanks a lot. 
I'm still searching for a way to see the result of my bash script on my terminal without actually running it on my pc.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks mate. kinda said the whole thing in the previous comment :d

Comment: @Sadra Welcome! What do you mean by "see the result without running it"? That's the part that doesn't make sense. Please [edit] the question and add an example.

Comment: @wjandrea there you go!

Comment: @Sadra What do you mean by "etc"? Like for example, do you want to see the output from `apt-get update`, without actually updating the package cache?

Comment: In addition to other suggestions made here, I'd suggest refactoring the apt-get line to only iterate on successes, i.e. `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y && sudo apt-get autoclean -y && sudo apt-get clean -y`.

Answer (score 2):

To see the results of running a bash file, a bash interpreter would have to interpret it. So the simple answer would be no.

*However*, if you are willing to use an online tool, you could run a bash script online. In this manner, you can see the results of running a bash script, without ever having to run it on your own machine.

A google search popped up these ones, but I cannot vouch for their legitimacy:

- https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online/ (for evaluating the results of a script)
- https://www.shellcheck.net/ (for assessing shell code quality)

Answer (score 2):

There's no general way to run a shell script without running it. You can sometimes sort-of *modify* the script to make it go through the motions without actually doing anything significant, but this requires understanding the script and the commands in it.

For example, in the update script in the question, you could just add `echo` before each `sudo apt-get` command, something like this (note that I've reformatted it a bit, and added quotes around some fixed strings):

```
echo '---------------'
echo 'hello and welcome to the automized bash file for your new linux distro!'
echo '---------------'

echo sudo apt-get update -y
echo sudo apt-get upgrade -y
echo sudo apt-get autoremove -y
...etc...
```

This will simply print the commands, rather than executing them. (Note: if any commands had redirections, e.g. `somecommand >outputfile` or `somecommand | anothercommand`, the adding `echo` doesn't remove the redirection, so you'll need to make other changes as well).

If you want to actually see what the various `apt-get` commands would do if you ran them... you're in luck, because `apt-get` happens to have a `--dry-run` option (see [the `man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) and [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445033/what-does-the-output-of-apt-get-install-dry-run-mean)).

Note that this is a feature specific to `apt-get`. Very few shell commands have an option like this, so it's not like some sort of universal just-try-it-out switch. In fact, not even all `apt-get` subcommands support `--dry-run`.

Most relevantly, `apt-get update` doesn't support `--dry-run`! And it wouldn't be useful if it did. If you don't start by updating the package indexes -- *actually* updating them, not just pretending to -- then the other `apt-get` commands won't be able to tell what's new, and won't actually tell you what needs to be changed.

If you don't actually-for-real update the indexes, then you can't tell what the rest of the script would do if it ran for real. So you could do something like this:

```
...
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade --dry-run --assume-no
sudo apt-get autoremove --dry-run --assume-no
...etc...
```

...but be aware the script *is* actually executing, and while *some* of its effects have been disabled, others haven't.